# what's the utility of bss segment?

Tags: c, memory, data-segment

I know that `bss` segment contains uninitialized variables which will be given 0 as initial value,but why we don't just use the `data` segment to store them?

I read that it speed up execution because the os loader initialize all these variables at once by calling memset, however, I'm not very convinced because the loader can call memset to initialize them in `data` segment also!

Comment: How would the loader know what part of the data segment contains the data that needs to be initialized? Often it's actually not the loader that does the clearing of that memory, but a routine that is linked with the application and runs before the calling of `main` (what is known as the C runtime, or CRT).

Comment: I found this answer very informative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46376748/1971003

Answer (score 3):

Because you might have a huge set of uninitialized values. You will have to fill the binary with zeros (or any value, for that matter, but *something* has to be there) if you were to use the data section for that purpose. Imagine adding a megabyte of zeros to the executable file...

Comment: Short version: it's to save space in the executable file.

Comment: i understand why the compiler should group them in the executable, but why the os loader store them in a separated logic segment in the memory!!!

Comment: @Pindexis I don't follow. Surely when you load, you cannot easily merge the two segments. You naturally load them into two different locations. That's not a big deal anyway.