# Why data segment of C was separated as two sections?

Tags: c, memory-layout, data-segment

All globally initialised values are stored in `.data` segment .i.e. initialised data segment and uninitialised values are stored in `bss` and compiler initialise those uninitialised values to zero automatically in `bss`. Then **why `data` segment is separated as `.data` and `bss`.**

Whether it has an advantage or not ? Or any benefit?

Comment: C did not innovate on this, linkers were already in common use before C was invented.  Pretty necessary, computers had very little memory back then.  BSS came from Fortran.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910006/12711

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C programming language (it is a specification written in English) does not know about `.bss` or `.data` or [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)s. Check that by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the latest draft of [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))).

In some cases (e.g. embedded computing) you don't have any data segment. For example  when you [cross-compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) for an [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/), the resulting code gets uploaded to the flash memory of that microcontroller (and data is in RAM, which your program would perhaps *explicitly* clear).

<sup>(most of my answer below is focused on Linux, but you could adapt it to other OSes)</sup>

Regarding the [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) on Unix-like systems like Linux, read more the specification of [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). It is *convenient* to avoid spending file space in the [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file for something (the [`.bss`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)) which is all zeros. The [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) code for [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) is able to set up an initial [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) with some cleared data (which is *not* [mapped to some file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) segment). See also [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) & [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html). Try some `cat /proc/$$/maps` command to understand the virtual address space of your shell. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

So the executable contains [segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation) (some of which are all zeros and don't take any disk space), and is constructed by the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) -which also handle [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing))- from several [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) provided by the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) from [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) files. On Linux, use [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) and [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) (and [nm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html)...) to explore and inspect ELF executables and ELF object files.

BTW a cleared data segment don't need to be fetched from disk by the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) subsystem, and that might make things *slightly* faster. The kernel would just clear a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) in RAM when it is [paged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) in.

So the `.bss` exist to avoid wasting disk space in executables (and to speedup initializing of zeroed data). Obviously, some mutable data is explicitly initialized to non-zero content (and that needs to sit in `.data` and takes some disk space in the executable). Constant immutable read-only data goes into `.rodata` (into the [text segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment#rodata), generally shared by several [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running the same program)

You could configure your linker (e.g. with some linker [script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html)) to put all the data (even the cleared ones) in some explicit [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) (but doing so is just  wasting disk space)...... Historically, [Unix have been developed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix) on [machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11#Unibus_models) with little but costly disk space (so wasting it was unthinkable at that time, hence the need of `.bss`; today you care less!)

Read Levine's book [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) for more, and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/).